# Lua - Extending Tables in loops

Tags: arrays, lua, lua-table, roblox

Note: This is in [Roblox's version of Lua](http://www.wiki.roblox.com/).
I have the following snippet of code:

```
for index, child in pairs(workspace.IMG:GetChildren()) do
    xyz = child.Position
    ImgScript = {}
    table.insert(ImgScript, -1, child.BrickColor.Number, xyz.X, xyz.Y, xyz.Z)
end
```

So `workspace.IMG` is a model that has a bunch of bricks in it. I am trying to turn that model into a script for [script builder](http://www.roblox.com/games/20279777/Voidacitys-Script-Builder-Working-Local). So I could make it do `Instance.new('Part', script) blah blah blah` for every brick, but that amounts to a large script. So instead I am making a table that has all of the necessary information (BrickColor and Position). Here is what I want the table to look like:

```
{{BrickColor Number, X, Y, Z}, {123, 14, 52, 65}, {156, 13, 52, 65}, etc.}
```

But the script I currently have doesn't make this kind of table. It doesn't do anything; In fact, I don't expect it to do what I am asking; I just don't know how to make it make this kind of table.

Comment: I tried concatenating instead of `table.insert` but it said I couldn't concatenate tables.

Comment: This is called [serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization). You might also look into a pre-written serializer for Roblox. See [this model](http://www.roblox.com/Serializer-FIXED-item?id=177599353).

Comment: @JamesT I've been looking for something like that for a long time, yet I somehow never found it. Thanks, but the string for ImgBrick models are too big, even with a low-res 50x50 image that is split into 3 parts. So thanks, I'll use that when I need to, but not for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put that line

```
ImgScript = {}
```

before the loop.  As it is, you're creating a new table (and discarding the previous one) on each iteration.

If you want the ImgScript table to start with the 'header' entry, add it there.

And, of course, the `table.insert` call should be

```
table.insert(ImgScript, {child.BrickColor.Number, xyz.X, xyz.Y, xyz.Z})
```

In the end, the whole script would be:

```
ImgScript = {{'BrickColor Number', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'}}
for index, child in pairs(workspace.IMG:GetChildren()) do
    local xyz = child.Position
    table.insert(ImgScript, {child.BrickColor.Number, xyz.X, xyz.Y, xyz.Z})
end
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you want this:

```
ImgScript = {}
for index, child in pairs(workspace.IMG:GetChildren()) do
    xyz = child.Position
    table.insert(ImgScript,{child.BrickColor.Number, xyz.X, xyz.Y, xyz.Z})
end
```

Comment: Thanks, this also worked but I had to give it to Javier for adding a little more explanation.